# How to configure emacs to show the file I was working on when I open emacs?

Tags: init-file, start-up

I have `save-place` and `save-visited-files` installed however whenever I start emacs first a directory list shows (result of another setting in .emacs), I close it and then a few message buffers show up and it's after closing all of them that I get to the file I was working on last time.
How can I configure emacs to show the file from last session when started?

Comment: Just `(require 'save-visited-files)` as last thing in your init file (especially after your directory list stuff) should do the trick. Note, that there must not be any other `require` for that library before. I.e., a `(assert (null (featurep 'save-visited-files)))` at this point must not quarrel.

Comment: The method from my last comment may fail if the directory list stuff plays around with `after-init-hook` as in the answer of Swarnendu Biswas.

Comment: In addition to the answers given so far, if you want to restore more than just the last file you were editing, you can save and restore your Emacs desktop. See the Emacs manual, node [Saving Emacs Sessions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following snippet to your init file to open the *last* file you were working on:

```
(require 'recentf)
(recentf-mode 1)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
           (lambda ()
              (recentf-open-most-recent-file 1)) t)
```

This enables `recentf`, which tracks the list of recent files you have opened. Then, you instruct Emacs to open the most recent file after initialization.

Note: If you use the `sync-recentf` package, then on starting Emacs, your first item will probably be `/tmp/sync-recentf-marker`. In that case, you might want to open the second-most recent file, or use a conditional checking for the file name.

If you always want to open a fixed file, then you can also set `initial-buffer-choice`.

Update: Added an optional third argument to the argument list of `add-hook` in order to append the hook to the end of the initialization based on suggestions from Tobias.

Comment: You should call `add-hook` with the `append` argument set to `t` to get your hook called at the very end of the initialization hooks. Maybe, some other library also adds stuff there.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. First I get "Welcome to emacs" then a log then scratch then the messages and its after closing these that I get the file I was working on last time.

Comment: Installed 11.88 using ELPA but Auctex doesn't show up when opening a TeX file. I uninstalled it.

Comment: This could help. `(add-to-list 'recentf-exclude "recentf")`